# PhoneGap, How to get app to work with API lvl10 using latest phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to get my app to work on a older device for testing purposes, the app currently uses the latest phonegap 2.5.0, the api level that i want to target is 2.3.3 api level 10.

I have tested the app on android level 4.2.2 and 4.0.3, it works perfectly fine. however when i decide to test it on  a device with android level 2.3.3 (API level 10). I am getting this error from Phonegap:

```
06-24 14:59:56.287: D/CordovaLog(342): processMessage failed: Message: S01 File934128106 s
06-24 14:59:56.287: I/Web Console(342): processMessage failed: Message: S01 File934128106 s at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.5.0.js:969

06-24 14:59:56.307: D/CordovaLog(342): processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Result of expression 'me.db' [null] is not an object.
06-24 14:59:56.307: I/Web Console(342): processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Result of expression 'me.db' [null] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.5.0.js:970

06-24 14:59:56.307: D/CordovaLog(342): processMessage failed: Stack: undefined
06-24 14:59:56.307: I/Web Console(342): processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Result of expression 'me.db' [null] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.5.0.js:970
```

Edit:

the phonegap makes these calls before the error, not sure if they are related:

```
06-24 15:42:41.715: D/CordovaLog(371): DroidGap:  onExceededDatabaseQuota estimatedSize: 2097152  currentQuota: 2097152  totalUsedQuota: 0
06-24 15:42:41.715: D/CordovaLog(371): calling quotaUpdater.updateQuota newQuota: 2097152
```

I am just trying to understand what is the cause of the error, and how can i fix it thanks.

Comment: why don't you use lastest phonegap version? it's already on version 2.8, also it should work fine, im using 2.8 targetting api lvl 8, and so far evrything works on evry android version

Comment: the 2.8 version, is causing some other issues and with the app so i just decided to leave it at 2.5 until than 3.0 comes out. however that shouldnt be an issue. I just need help in understanding whats causing this error